# using single storedprocedure with triggers, insert two different tables with the values of one main table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers

Let me explain this briefly,I am having three different tables described with their columns below:-

```
Table1:- tbl_asset
        ID 
        ItemID 
        ItemQuantity
        ItemLocation
        ItemSubLocation
        UnitPrice

Table2:- tbl_stock
        ID 
        AssetID
        ItemID
        ItemQuantity
        StockType
        StockMode

Table3:- tbl_profile
        ID
        StockID
        ProfileID
        ItemID
        CreatedBy
        CreatedDate
```

How can i insert the values for all the tables with use of single insert procedure for the table **"tbl_asset"** (may be with Triggers)
Could anyone help me?

Comment: in this 3 table which table is main table?

Comment: it possible using only one trigger. give me your all filed of all table

Comment: i have updated the table fields ! Please take a look !

Answer (score 0):

try this if any issue or any confusion than reply me

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS NAME_OF_TRIGGER;

CREATE TRIGGER NAME_OF_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_asset 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        INSERT INTO tbl_stock(AssetID,ItemID,ItemQuantity,StockType,StockMode)
        SELECT ID,ItemID,ItemQuantity,"StockType","StockMode"
        FROM tbl_asset 
        WHERE ID=NEW.ID;        
END;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS NAME_OF_TRIGGER;

CREATE TRIGGER NAME_OF_TRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT ON tbl_stock 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        INSERT INTO tbl_profile(StockID,ItemID,ProfileID,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)
        SELECT ID,ItemID,"ProfileID","CreatedBy","CreatedDate"
        FROM tbl_stock 
        WHERE ID=NEW.ID       
END;
```

Comment: for the second insert statement, "StockID" should get it from the table "tbl_stock" not from "tbl_asset" ("tbl_asset" does not have the field "StockID")

Comment: can two trigger possible?